# Add page numbers to a Pdf document

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf

How can I extend the content of a pdf to next page if content of pdf does not all fit on a single page. Currently I am creating Pdf as A4.

Also how can I specify the numbers of pages e.g. Page 1 of 12 in bottom right.

Answer (score 5):

To add text to a PDF document and have it create new pages if the text doesn't fit you can use the following code.

```
theID = theDoc.AddHtml(theText)
While theDoc.Chainable(theID)
  theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage()
  theDoc.FrameRect
  theID = theDoc.AddHtml("", theID)
Wend
```

To add your page numbers and page count to each page use this.

```
theDoc.Rect = "100 50 500 150" 'position of page number
For i = 1 To theDoc.PageCount
  theDoc.PageNumber = i
  theDoc.AddText i & "/" & theDoc.PageCount
Next
```

**Edit: C# version**

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
int id = doc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com/", true, 700, true);
while (true)
{
    if (!doc.Chainable(id))
        break;
    doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
    id = doc.AddImageToChain(id);
 }

 doc.Font = doc.AddFont("Arial");
 doc.FontSize = 9;
 for (int i = 1; i <= doc.PageCount; i++)
 {
     doc.PageNumber = i;
     doc.Rect.String = "470 55 570 65";
     doc.HPos = 1;
     doc.AddText("Page " + i.ToString() + " of " + doc.PageCount.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Question tagged as C#

Comment: Valid point @Askolein. I will update my answer. Only 2 years too late :(

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is first make sure you have a document that will automaticly expand to the size required, the c# example below will take a URL and build a document up to 50 pages, expand if needed. (The example below adds space in the document for a header and footer)

```
  private static Doc CreateNewDoument(string currentURL)
        {
            var theDoc = new Doc();

            theDoc.MediaBox.String = "A4";

            theDoc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheEnabled = false;
            theDoc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 101;
            theDoc.Rect.Width = 719;
            theDoc.Rect.Height = 590;
            theDoc.Rect.Position(2, 70);
            theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;

            // Add url to document.););
            try
            {
                //Make sure we dont have a cached page.. 
                string pdfUrl = currentURL+ "&discache=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

                int theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(pdfUrl);
                //Add up to 50 pages
                for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
                {
                    if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
                        break;
                    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
                    theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
                }
                theDoc.PageNumber = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(pdCurrentURL);

                throw new ApplicationException("Error generating pdf..." + "Exception: " + ex + "<br/>URL for render: " + pdfUrl+ "<br/>Base URL: " + currentURL);
            }

            return theDoc;
        }
```

Then to add a footer to each page just use the following method. Method below adds a blue box with text inside.

```
    private static Doc AddFooter(Doc theDoc)
    {
        int theCount = theDoc.PageCount;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 590 50";
            theDoc.Rect.Position(13, 30);
            System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#468DCB");
            theDoc.Color.Color = c;
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.FillRect();

        }
        i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 260 50";
            theDoc.Rect.Position(190, 20);
            System.Drawing.Color cText = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
            theDoc.Color.Color = cText;
            string theFont = "Century Gothic";
            theDoc.Font = theDoc.AddFont(theFont);
            theDoc.FontSize = 17;
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.AddText("Page " + i +" of " +theCount); //Setting page number  
            //theDoc.FrameRect();
        }
        return theDoc;
    }
```

Then just call the whole lot.. like

```
        private static bool BuildPDF(string pdfPath)
    {
        bool pdfBuilt = false;

        try
        {
            var theDoc = new Doc();

            string pdGeneral = "http://ww.myurl.com";
            theDoc = CreateNewDoument(pdGeneral);

            theDoc = AddFooter(theDoc);

            theDoc.Save(pdfPath);
            theDoc.ClearCachedDecompressedStreams();
            theDoc.Clear();
            theDoc.Dispose();

            pdfBuilt = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //PDF normaly in use dont worry..
        }

        return pdfBuilt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

abc pdf is used to Convert HTML page to pdf, set your content into two html pages, it will generate two pages in PDF. For more details you can view [This](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8/)  in this on the left hand side there is "content" here click on **Examples** then select "**paged HTML Example**".